# How to repeat notification on specific time in android through service

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have create a notification panel but there is some problem .
I have created a service for this but notification is not repeating.
I am not understanding whats problem.
Here is my code:

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button b1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , Notification.class);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 20*1000 , pendingIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`Notification.java`

```
public class Notification extends Service{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Notification", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

        android.app.Notification notification = new android.app.Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"New Message", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,NotificationView.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "hahaha","U have recived new message", pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(9999, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml` I declared permission for alarm and declered service.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<service android:name=".Notification"></service>
```

there is a problem, when i click on button then service start an notification show.but notification is not repeating.

Comment: The `AlarmManager#setRepeating()` method is inexact since KitKat. Also, you're setting the alarm to repeat every 20 seconds, which is probably going to get pushed up to at least a minute in current Android versions. If you need an interval that short, it's not recommended to use `AlarmManager`.

Answer (score 1):

You are making the notification using the same id (9999 in your case). So when a new notification is made, all it does is replace the existing notification. So as far you see, only one notification shows up. To see different notifications, you should change the id of your notification in your notify() method.

The other option would be to check if a notification is already displayed (I believe this feature is relatively new) and then update the existing notification to let the user know that a new one has been received.

**EDIT:**
Besides this, you are only creating the notification once because you only initialize the Notification service once. The next time the alarm manager repeats it sees that the service is already started and does not initialize a new instance. You will have to stop the service before the next scheduled period for the alarm manager to initialize it once again.

This is anyway not advisable. If you need notifications to be scheduled repeatedly, construct notification in a background thread in a service at routine intervals within a loop until a certain condition is met.

Comment: i have changed id but not working only one time notification is showing..
when i clicked on button. why my service class is not repeating.
@ucsunil

Comment: Oh.. I see the problem now. You are creating the service only once actually although it looks like the AlarmManager is repeating. I will edit my answer.